# why JavaFx Media Player and Media View don'r work on some Labtop and work on a another?

Tags: java, windows, javafx-2, javafx-8

I was trying to play some audio and video files on a laptop using`JavaFX MediaPlayer and MediaView` but the media didn't work and also the application didn't give any exceptions, but when i moved the application to another laptop it worked well

Both Laptops are HP and working on MS Widows 8 OS, under JDK 8u102

here's the source code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Anoos
 */
public class Task1 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException {

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                Media media
                        = new Media(new File("002.mp3").
                                toURI().toURL().toString());
                System.out.println(media.getSource());
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
                player.play();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

so, can any one help me please ?

and thank you in advance (:

Comment: Have tried running in debug mode and see if you get no exceptions in the output window?

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly, thank you for replaying; in real i didn't because every thing go fine expect playing media

Comment: you have a `try catch` block in your handle method for any `Exception e` which might explain why you don't see an error. My only guess as of now will be that the file is not found or can't be opened. Add `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` block and see what happens.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly i tried it, but also nothing, surely the file exists,  and i will update the question now with e.printStackTrace()  ISA , i hope i am not annoying person (:

Comment: Does the file size for `002.mp3` on both computer is the same?

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly, Yes they are completely identical , they are the same